# Flutter IOS build Xcode GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m import error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Flutter app Android build working fine and uploaded on Google Play. When imported into Xcode and following steps as per Flutter getting the following error

```
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<share/FLTSharePlugin.h>)
#import <share/FLTSharePlugin.h>
#else
@import share;    [error comes here: module share does not exist]
#endif

#if __has_include(<webview_flutter/FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.h>)
#import <webview_flutter/FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin.h>
#else
@import webview_flutter;
#endif

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [FLTSharePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTSharePlugin"]];
  [FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTWebViewFlutterPlugin"]];
}

@end
```

All prerequisite settings and configuration has been done. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webView in your application try to adding a boolean property to the app's Info.plist file with the key io.flutter.embedded_views_preview and the value YES

Comment: Yes the app runs web view in it, its one dart file only. on Android no issues but when i open it ios folder in xcode, it throws this issue.

Comment: Tried io.flutter.embedded_views_preview and it didnt work, still same error.